# Poison Distribution: Yearly event to monthly event

Tags: poisson-distribution

Consider the following question as example.

> When biking to school you have an average of 2 flat tires a year. What
> is the chance of having to flat tires in one month?

I know how I'd use the Poisson Distribution to calculate the probability of zero of five flat tires, using the following Python code:

```
x = range(0, 5)
r = stats.poisson.pmf(x, 2)
print(r)
```

However, how would I calculate it for a month? I tried reasoning that I should multiple the `2` with 12 because there are 12 months in a year but that did not give the desired result of **0,01176**. I have no clue on how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a month is one-twelfth as long as a year, your Poisson parameter for a month's worth of flat tires should be $\lambda_{\rm month}=\frac{2}{12}$, rather than $2\cdot 12$.